# Beamer: currentsection and currentsubsection highlight differently

Tags: beamer, sectioning

Consider the folllowing code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=BrickRed]{structure} 
\usetheme{Singapore}
\begin{document}

\section{Section No 1}
\subsection{SubSection No 1}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsubsection]}
\frame{Some text 1}
\subsection{SubSection No 2}
\subsection{SubSection No 3}
\frame{Some text 2}

\section{Section No 2}
\subsection{SubSection No 1}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsubsection]}
\frame{Some more text 1}
\subsection{SubSection No 2}
\subsection{SubSection No 3}
\frame{Some more text 2}

\end{document}
```

Now when we look at the frames with `currentsection` then only the current section+its subsections are highlighted and all other sections+subsections are properly grayed out. If we use `currentsubsection`, then only the other subsections are grayed out but not the sections. How can I also gray out the sections?

See:
[image: just a picture describing the situation]

Comment: @dcmst Oh that's excellent. Precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usecolortheme[named=BrickRed]{structure} 
\usetheme{Singapore}
\begin{document}

\section{Section No 1}
\subsection{SubSection No 1}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection, currentsubsection]} %new code
\frame{Some text 1}
\subsection{SubSection No 2}
\subsection{SubSection No 3}
\frame{Some text 2}

\section{Section No 2}
\subsection{SubSection No 1}
\frame{\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]}  %new code
\frame{Some more text 1}
\subsection{SubSection No 2}
\subsection{SubSection No 3}
\frame{Some more text 2}

\end{document}
```

By Using `\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]` the **other** sections will be shaded. I think this is a sound behaviour since we are in a certain section so it's right for it not to be shaded.

[image]